# Making a Java Makefile

Tags: java, makefile

EDIT: Essentially, I am trying to do the same thing as typing "javac sim.java" and then "java sim (commands)". Is there a way to replace this using a makefile?

So I have looked at a lot of examples online and tried to modify them to what I need, but nothing has worked.  I need a makefile so that my teacher can create my project just by typing "make" into terminal (this is a requirement of the project for some reason).  My end goal is to be able to type "sim" followed by the required commands as defined by my code.  The code runs in eclipse, but I can't get it to run using these commands in terminal. It will make the file, but it says "sim: command not found" when I try to type "sim....(arguments)" into terminal.
I'm sure this is a dumb question but we have not learned about this in school and I have no experience with Makefile.

Below is my makefile.

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
OPT = -O3
#OPT = -g
WARN = -Wall

sim: sim.class

sim.class: sim.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) sim.java

clean:
    $(RM) sim.class

clobber:
    $(RM) sim.class
```

Comment: Use **[ant](http://ant.apache.org)** for Java. It's an XML interface and pretty easy to learn and use. The learning curve isn't that big and in the long run it's a good skill and tool for those developing in Java. That's how people typically create the build environment for Java projects, at least bigger ones. But it is perfect for smaller ones too. It scales well, lets you handle complex cases, or build environment variables and things not necessarily known until build time.

Comment: You don't have a recipe defined for building `sim` from `sim.class`.  So, make doesn't do that, and no file named `sim` is created.

Comment: a requirement of the project is that the teacher is able to just type "make" to be able to use it

Comment: What do you mean by 'use'? Run it, or just have it be sitting there ready to run?

Comment: use it to compile it so it is ready to run just by typing the word "sim"

Comment: No such thing unless your professor is offering you a nonstandard tool or you add a shell script named 'sim' to invoke Java.

Answer (score 7):

For a simple project without many files or dependencies, I simply use scripts.

To build:

```
javac -cp .;* *.java
```

To run:

```
java -cp .;* SomeMainClass
```

Replace `.` with whatever path(s) you need for your source. The * will use any jar on the default path or use a different path like `lib/*`.

Answer (score 7):

Using make with java can be an exercise in driving screws with a hammer as soon as you have more than one class.

Working java code will use packages. So you'll have a complex directory tree that mirrors your package structure, with your .java source files in it. Writing make rules that 'see' all those files is a pain.

You should invoke javac on all your source files at the same time to get correct results. So, the usual make pattern of 'run one command to turn one source file into one compiled file' does not work so well.

However, it seems as if your main problem at the moment is that you expect java to produce an executable; a file with a name like 'sim'. Nope, not going to happen in any simple way. The java compiler produces .class files; a whole tree of them for your source files. You can run directly from them, or you can package them up in a JAR file.

To get all the way to something that appears to be a simple command line executable, you need to use a more complex tool that wraps all this up with a script on the front.

For now, you just need to do:

```
java -cp . NAME_OF_THE_CLASS_IN_sim.java
```

to run after your makefile completes.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a simple directory layout like the following,

```
root/
    src/
        ExampleClass.java
        AnotherClass.java
    out/
makefile
```

you could create your `makefile` like this:

```makefile
##
# source directory
##
SRC_DIR := src

##
# output directory
##
OUT_DIR := out

##
# sources
##
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.java)

##
# classes
## 
CLS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%.java=$(OUT_DIR)/%.class)

##
# compiler and compiler flags
##
JC := javac
JCFLAGS := -d $(OUT_DIR)/ -cp $(SRC_DIR)/

##
# suffixes
##
.SUFFIXES: .java

##
# targets that do not produce output files
##
.PHONY: all clean

##
# default target(s)
##
all: $(CLS)

$(CLS): $(OUT_DIR)/%.class: $(SRC_DIR)/%.java
    $(JC) $(JCFLAGS) $<

##
# clean up any output files
##
clean:
    rm $(OUT_DIR)/*.class
```

Answer (score 3):

make executes a recipe by executing its dependencies, then the recipe itself. Therefore if you add a command which runs your compiled code to the top recipe, typing 'make' will also run the code after it is compiled. I cannot believe how many people do not know this!

Something like:

```
sim: sim.class
    java sim
```

Will do what your tutor requires.

Comment: Good practice to add `.PHONY: sim` so if there is accidentally a file named 'sim' in the directory, this will still get run.