# How does Java handle linking during compilation?

Tags: java, compilation, linker

I have a makefile where one Java class pretty high on the hierarchy depends on a ton of other classes. My basic question is can I do the following:

$(bigClass).class: $(smallOne).class ... $(lastSmallOne).class $(bigClass).java

javac bigClass.java smallOne.java ... lastSmallOne.java

and it still be optimal. Does javac take care of that all for me? Or do I need to go through linking details like with gcc and c code? In other words, if only one of those was not updated, would javac figure out "oh...okay...all i need to do is compile this one right here and then re-link"? If not, what's the javac equivalent for the simple statement "gcc -o object1.o object2.o"?

Comment: There's no linking step in Java.  You never turn the bytecode into an executable, you instead hand it to a Java Virtual Machine which does just-in-time compilation to actually run it.

Comment: Why are you trying to [use make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184999/making-a-java-makefile) to build Java anyway?  You should really consider using a modern tool like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: Using `make` to build Java - you seem to have a certain masochistic streak...

Comment: @azurefrog - There is a linking step, but it occurs automatically when you run the Java bytecode, which might or might not be compiled by the VM.

Comment: @AndyThomas Well, it's true that dynamic linking happens during execution, but this question is specifically asking about linking a program together during compilation.  I guess I should have been more specific and said that "there's no linking *prior to execution* in Java".

Answer (score 0):

if bigClass uses smallOne (like member variable or static reference to method, etc..) then java will build them both, you only need to supply the main class